# How can we make controls in a carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just made a text carousel and don't know how to make its controls, the left and the right control. Please help me to get through it. I'm new to JQuery

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1bc8j418/

OR you can see my code here

Here is my HTML

```
        <div class="carouselBg">
            <p id="demoSliderFirst" class="textSliders"> 
                Life must be lived forwards, but can only be understood backwards.  
            </p>
        </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.carouselBg{
   min-height: 300px;
   max-width: 700px;
   position: relative;
   top: 70px;
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #AC8157;
}
.textSliders{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding:50px;
  padding-top:130px;
}
```

Here is my JQUERY

```
var demoSlider1 = $('#demoSliderFirst');
var DemoSliderSet1 = [
'Do not dwell in the past, do not dream of the future, concentrate the mind on the present moment',
'What screws us up the most in life is the picture in our head of how it is supposed to be.',
'Life shrinks or expands in proportion to one’s courage.'];
var index1 = 0;

function demoSliderCarousel1(){

    var newDemoSliderSet1 = DemoSliderSet1[index1];

    demoSlider1.fadeOut('400',function(){
        demoSlider1[0].innerHTML = newDemoSliderSet1;
    }).fadeIn('400');


    index1++;

    if(index1 >= DemoSliderSet1.length){
        index1 = 0;
    }

}

setInterval(demoSliderCarousel1,4000);
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ? Because if you do , it includes the controls

Comment: do you see any bootstrap class in my code? i'm making custom carousel

Comment: Then y have you tagged bootstrap?